# How can I get the number of touches made on the view using the iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I want to get number of touches made on the view. If I touch the image with single finger I want to get the count as one and if I touch the image with two fingers I want to get the value as two.

I'm using the following code.

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    NSArray *allTouches = [touches allObjects];
    int count = [allTouches count];
    printf("\n the count is :%d",count);
}
```

Here I'm getting the count always as 1, even when I touch with two fingers.

Comment: Check that your target view has multitouch enabled. If it's not you'll always get one.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is probably multitouch being disabled. Enable it.

```
yourView.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;
```

Answer (score 1):

@Deepak is right. Check the property for the view. The reference documents for [UIResponder](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIResponder) clearly states

> Multiple touches are disabled by
>   default. In order to receive multiple
>   touch events you must set the a
>   **multipleTouchEnabled** property of the
>   corresponding view instance to YES.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just take `int count = [touches count];` from your original `NSSet` and be done with it?

Comment: Okay, but using this also I'm getting the count value as one .

Comment: Oh yeah, do what these other guys are saying.